# Bokeh plotting data not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, bokeh

I would like to plot a file like [THIS](http://aflyax.github.io/images/world_yall.png) with bokeh. I tried to import the following packages but its not working:

in my py file:

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, legend
output_notebook()
```

ERROR:

```
 File "plot.py", line 4
        from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, legend, output_notebook()
                                                                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo python plot.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "plot.py", line 4, in <module>
        from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, legend
    ImportError: cannot import name legend
```

Comment: Looks like legend is not a method of bokeh.plotting, so you can not import it. Why do you need it anyway? Legend for plots works just fine

Comment: cause I want to print out a legend... @Sleepyhead

Comment: legend seems to be working just fine... just don't import legend